# Solving First Order Separable Differentials

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So I've began working on separable differentials, first order, and the basic ones are easy to grasp. Then this:

$y'=x+y$ let $u=x+y$

I've tried mixing u-sub, implicit differentiation but haven't had any success. Where do in start on something like this? Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isnt a separable differential equation as x+y cannot be written as X(x)Y(y) for X,Y functions of x,y respectively.

Try

$\frac{dy}{dy}-y=x$ then multiply it by $e^{\int -1 dx}=e^{-x}$ to get

$e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dy}-e^{-x}y=e^{-x}x$ then use product rule to get

$\frac{d}{dx}\Big( e^{-x}y \Big)=e^{-x}x$ which integrates to

$e^{-x}y=\int xe^{-x}dx = -e^{-x}(x+1)+C$ to get

$y=-(x+1)+Ce^x$

Comment: hrm, how would i go about solving it?

Comment: Wolfram gave me the same thing  but I don't know where they pulled $e^(\int{-1}dx)$ from

Comment: it is called an integrating factor

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor

Comment: You just have to learn the method. The integrating factor is introduced so that you can use the product rule

Comment: Woah - thank-you. It was just a few sections ahead of where i was at in the book under Linear Equations.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an integrating factor :

$$y' = x+y \Longleftrightarrow y' - y = x \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-x}y)' = xe^{-x}$$

From here, integrate both sides and multiply by $e^{x}$ to get an expression for $y$.